# How to stop a function from executing multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently facing an issue and could not solve it.. 
I have 3 slideshows located on one page, where only one slideshow is visible and the other 2 are hidden, based on which slideshow the user selects.
The visible slideshow auto-plays the slides and can be navigated with arrows, but at the moment when I try to change from slideshow 1 to slideshow 2 and then back again to slideshow 1, the function on slideshow 1 gets executed 2 times and sometimes even 3 or 4 times (depending on how often I change slideshows back and forth) making me unable to navigate it.. How do I "cancel" the function that keeps running on the previous slideshow, at the moment when I change from slideshow 1 to 2 and prevent it from executing multiple times?

Thank you in advance and I hope there's someone that can help me out on this one!

```
function Slider() {
    this.slider = document.getElementsByClassName("image_slideshow");
    if (typeof(this.slider) !== 'undefined' && this.slider !== null){
        this.radio = document.getElementsByName("room");
        this.room_labels = document.getElementsByClassName("selected_room")[0];
        this.label = this.room_labels.getElementsByTagName("label");
        this.slideIndex = 1;
        this.timer = null;
        this.initEvents();
    }
}
Slider.prototype = {
        initEvents : function(){
                var room_labels = this.room_labels, label = this.label, slider;

                for (var k = 0; k < label.length; k++) {
                    var radio = document.getElementById(label[k].className);

                    if(radio.checked){
                        slider = document.getElementById(radio.id + "_room").getElementsByClassName("image_slideshow")[0];

                        this.playSlider(this.slideIndex, slider);
                    }

                }

            room_labels.addEventListener("click", function(event){ event = event || window.event;
                    var target = event.target;
                    if (target && target !== undefined && target !== null){
                        if (target.nodeName === "LABEL") {
                                slider = document.getElementById(target.className + "_room").getElementsByClassName("image_slideshow")[0];

                                this.playSlider(this.slideIndex,slider);
                        }

                    return;
                    }
            }.bind(this));
        },
        playSlider : function(n, slider){
            var prev = slider.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0], 
                            next = slider.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];

            prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex -= 1,slider);
            }.bind(this));

            next.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += 1,slider);
            }.bind(this));


            this.showSlides(this.slideIndex,slider);
        },
        showSlides : function(n, slider){
                var self = this, slides = slider.getElementsByTagName("figure"),
                                bullets = slider.getElementsByClassName("indicator")[0].children;

                if (n > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1;}
                if (n < 1) {this.slideIndex = slides.length;}

                for (var i=0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].className = "";
                        bullets[i].className = " bullet";
                }

                slides[this.slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
                bullets[this.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
   self.showSlides(self.slideIndex += 1,slider);}, 7000);}

};

window.Slider = new Slider();
```

Comment: From reading the code, I think you shouldn't call `addEventListener` more than once. Each time `playSlider` is called it registers another event listener. You should probably move this logic to the initialization part of your code, or check if you have already registered once

Comment: The idea of this approach is good. However, I'd suggest you to create all the elements for the slider dynamically in the constructor, and assign them to the properties of an instance. Then in the methods, refer the elements only via `this`. This requires a bit more code in the constructor, but reduces it in the methods. And you can always rely on the properties of an instance to really refer the elements in the slider the instance controls. Also this way you can be sure the event listeners get to attached to the correct elements.